# Pagination links created by jQuery Bootstrap Paginator plugin are floating to right

Tags: jquery, jsf, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, jsf-2.2

I am using Java Server Faces 2.2. My design is based on Twitter Bootstrap 3. Boostrap offers a component for styling a pagination. I am using this jQuery Plugin (http://bootstrappaginator.org/) to generate the pagination dynamically.

Inside my templates i am generating links with `h:outputLink`. I created a table with `h:dataTable` which is pageable and sortable. The page, the sort field and the sort order are passed as get parameters. The links are created with `h:outputLink`.

The problem is now that the links for the pagination are created by the jQuery plugin and inserted into the page. Also i am using jQuery to adjust dynamically the position of the pagination (floating it to the right) because the option of plugin is not working.

After loading the page the pagination is floated to the right side. Now i am using the pagination to switch to an other page. The jquery plugin now regenerates the pagination. The pagination is now floated to the left (the plugin resets the class attribute of the `<ul>` tag). After that the pagination is floated to the right (i am adding the missing class by jquery).

The problem is that you can see this floating to the right in the browser. That bevavior does not occour if i am using the links created by `h:outputLink`. `h:outputLink` adds something like `id="j_idt75:j_idt84" name="j_idt75:j_idt84"` to the link. Is this for ajax? I think the jquery plugin generated links are also creating a ajax request, which updates the complete page so i am able to see the movement of the pagination.

What can i do to avoid this behavior? I think the "standard" html links without the ids should force a complete new get request and not an ajax request. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that alignment options is not supported with bootstrap version 3.
Here's link to [bug report](https://github.com/lyonlai/bootstrap-paginator/issues/14)

Alignment options is working only in version 2. If you use bootstrap-paginator version 3, it doesn't set alignment at all.
Here's the problematic code in bootstrap-paginator.js:

```
if (this.options.bootstrapMajorVersion === 2) {
    switch (alignment.toLowerCase()) {
        case "center":
            this.$element.addClass("pagination-centered");
            break;
        case "right":
            this.$element.addClass("pagination-right");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

There is no `pagination-centered` nor `pagination-right` classes in bootstrap version 3 styles. Your options are either use bootstrap version 2 or to create your own solution with styles.

Here's my solution. I've put pagination  inside  and then apply style to the parent div element. If you do it before calling paginator function it should style correct right from the beginning.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap Paginator V3 Tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/qunit-1.11.0.css">
    <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css" -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrapv3.css">
    <script src="../lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../lib/bootstrapv3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../src/bootstrap-paginator.js"></script>
    <style>
    .pagination-centered {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .pagination-right {
      text-align: right;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body width="100%">
    <div>
        <ul id="example1"></ul>
    </div><br/>
    <div>
        <ul id="example2"></ul>
    </div><br/>
    <div>
        <ul id="example3"></ul>
    </div><br/> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var opts = {
            bootstrapMajorVersion:3,
            currentPage: 3,
            numberOfPages: 5,
            totalPages:11
        }
        var optsCenter = {
            bootstrapMajorVersion:3,
            currentPage: 3,
            numberOfPages: 5,
            totalPages:11,
            alignment: 'center'
        }
        var optsRight = {
            bootstrapMajorVersion:3,
            currentPage: 3,
            numberOfPages: 5,
            totalPages:11,
            alignment: 'right'
        }
        alignElement($('#example1'), opts);
        $('#example1').bootstrapPaginator(opts);
        alignElement($('#example2'), optsCenter);
        $('#example2').bootstrapPaginator(optsCenter);
        alignElement($('#example3'), optsRight);
        $('#example3').bootstrapPaginator(optsRight);
        function alignElement(element, options) {
            if (!options.alignment) return;
                switch (options.alignment.toLowerCase()) {
                    case "center":
                        element.parent().addClass("pagination-centered");
                        break;
                    case "right":
                        element.parent().addClass("pagination-right");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```